# Making Fluxbox look pretty

Tags: fluxbox

I'm trying to setup Fluxbox to look nice on my machine as I familiar with it and find it functional.

One thing stoping me from moving to it fulltime, while seemingly trivial, is that it looks *ugly*. I have a 1680x1050 screen and fluxbox does not seem to have even basic anti-alliasing.

Menus and corners of windows look jagged and, well, not nice.

What can I do to make Fluxbox look nicer? e.g. include anti-alliasing, maybe get transparency working....

Comment: With this type of visual occurrence, a relevant screenshot will improve the answers significantly. Additionally I recommend you annotate the screenshot, with a clearly visible circle or arrow.  Once you know all the \*nix technical jargon, then you *might* be able to get by without a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fluxbox-binary that is linked against the [XFT-library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xft), then you can use anti-aliased fonts in fluxbox.

**Menus and corners**: corners only look jagged when you use a style which uses "rounded corners". The rounded corners feature is achieved by using the shape-extension of X11 and that is a bitmap-mask, there is no way to antialias this. Use rectangle-like corners and they are not jagged anymore. I do not know what you mean by "menus are looking jagged".

The official resources on fluxbox help are:

- http://fluxbox.org
- http://fluxbox-wiki.org/

You should find information about how to customize fluxbox in a way that leads you to something that you might find nicer looking, whatever that is in "objective terms".

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to set up Fluxbox:

- Rounded corners: http://wiki.fluxbox.org/index.php?title=Rounded_corners
- Keyboard shortcuts: http://wiki.fluxbox.org/index.php?title=Keyboard_shortcuts
- Edit the startup file: http://wiki.fluxbox.org/index.php?title=Editing_the_startup_file
- Add styles: http://wiki.fluxbox.org/index.php?title=Styles